# Eclipse: how to access 2 SVN repos with same username but different password?

Tags: eclipse, svn, passwords

I have 2 repositories and I'm using the same username to access them, but with different passwords (the 2 repos are on the same server but I need different credentials for each repo). In Eclipse (Version: Indigo Service Release 1, Build id: 20110916-0149) with the Subclipse SVN plugin if I click 'Remember password' for one repository, then it won't work for the other (since it's the same username, so it'll prompt for password).
Is it possible to have the credentials stored "per repository" and not global (i.e. to have 2 accounts with same username but different password, one for repo1 and the other for repo2)?

Comment: Could you add your SVN adapter you use? There could be 2: SVNKit or JavaHL. Depending on that (and your operating system), the storage of ID and password may be different.

Comment: I use JavaHL v1.7.2. It seems if the base URL is different, then it's not a problem having the same username with different passwords. But these 2 repos are both on the same server and Eclipse/Subclipse plugin expects that if the username is the same, then also the password should be the same, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, but a hint what to check further:

- Go to your Subversion configuration directory. Under Windows it is: `c:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\`
- There you should find the directory `auth/svn.simple`.
- It contains for each SVN repository (not: server) a file with information about the repo and the user ID and password that SVN uses to authenticate to the server.

  ```
  V 65
  <http://server.name:80> Subversion MYREPO
  ```
- This indicates, that it could be different for each repo. I have two entries for the same server, but different repos. Because we use LDAP, the crypted passwords are the same

So you could delete the entries, and try the following steps again:

1. Restart eclipse
2. Delete your checkout locations
3. Delete the password information inside eclipse
4. Ensure that there is nothing cached in `auth/svn.simple`.
5. Create a new checkout location in Eclipse, and store your password. You should now have a new entry for that repository only.
6. If you create another checkout location for the different repository, you should have the option to define user ID and password again. And this should result then in a different entry.

I hope that helps to debug your problem.

Comment: Thanks to your hints I was able to find the reason why I only had one entry and not 2 (in auth/svn.simple): the definition for the 2 repository locations used the same AuthName; so when I was creating the second location in Eclipse, it was trying to use the same credentials because the AuthName was the same (and in auth/svn.simple there was only 1 file corresponding to the first created location).So thanks again for your help!

Comment: What on Earth is 'AuthName' and where do I set it to solve this problem. The 'definition of a repository location' has no such thing.